# sql server getting records >= 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records that are older than 7 days, the column is a unix time column in milliseconds.

```
SELECT 
   ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician", wo.WORKORDERID "Request ID", 
   aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester", ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician",
   wotodesc.FULLDESCRIPTION "Description",
   DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(s, wo.CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00'), getDate()) "Created Time",
   std.STATUSNAME "Request Status" 
FROM 
   WorkOrder wo 
LEFT JOIN 
   SDUser sdu ON wo.REQUESTERID = sdu.USERID 
LEFT JOIN 
   AaaUser aau ON sdu.USERID = aau.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
   WorkOrderToDescription wotodesc ON wo.WORKORDERID = wotodesc.WORKORDERID 
LEFT JOIN 
   WorkOrderStates wos ON wo.WORKORDERID = wos.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN SDUser 
   td ON wos.OWNERID = td.USERID 
LEFT JOIN 
   AaaUser ti ON td.USERID = ti.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
   StatusDefinition std ON wos.STATUSID = std.STATUSID
WHERE  
   (std.STATUSNAME != N'Closed' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) 
   OR (std.STATUSNAME IS NULL) 
   AND (DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(s, wo.CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00'), getDate()) >= 7)
ORDER BY
   ti.FIRST_NAME
```

In the where clause I am putting an and the dateconvert >= 7 but i am getting records that are younger than 7 days.

```
    WORKORDERID REQUESTERID OBOID   CREATEDBYID CREATEDTIME
           1          16    NULL    1           1396297257760
           2          23    NULL    23          1396455478406
           3          23    NULL    1           1396742357038
```

Example rows put in.

Comment: i am showing a order put in on May 02 2014 which is saying 91 days old but internet is showing 88 days since that date something in my conversion is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your ANDs and ORs need sorting.  Maybe try this:-

```
 SELECT ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician",wo.WORKORDERID "Request ID",aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester",ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician",
    wotodesc.FULLDESCRIPTION "Description",DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(s, wo.CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00'), getDate()) "Created Time",
    std.STATUSNAME "Request Status" 
    FROM WorkOrder wo 
    LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu 
    ON wo.REQUESTERID=sdu.USERID 
    LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau 
    ON sdu.USERID=aau.USER_ID 
    LEFT JOIN WorkOrderToDescription wotodesc 
    ON wo.WORKORDERID=wotodesc.WORKORDERID 
    LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos 
    ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID
    LEFT JOIN SDUser td 
    ON wos.OWNERID=td.USERID 
    LEFT JOIN AaaUser ti 
    ON td.USERID=ti.USER_ID 
    LEFT JOIN StatusDefinition std 
    ON wos.STATUSID=std.STATUSID
    WHERE  ((std.STATUSNAME != N'Closed' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) OR (std.STATUSNAME IS NULL)) AND (DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(s, wo.CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00'), getDate()) >= 7)
    order by ti.FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: Yes now only the rows with 7 and older, but i am showing a order put in on May 02 2014 is 91 days old but everywhere is showing 88 days since that date.

Comment: Am i doing my date conversion wrong i am showing the records to be off

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    WHERE  ((std.STATUSNAME != N'Closed' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) OR (std.STATUSNAME IS NULL) ) AND (DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(s, wo.CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00'), getDate()) >= 7)
```